# How do I unmaximize a window with xdotool or similar by command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, gtk, xdotools

With xdotool or wmctrl I can move or modify window attributes but if it is maximized none of the commands work. How do I "unmaximize" the window?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz`